# Is the new GUI plotting for GNU Octave available as a C#/C++ library?

Tags: c#, c++, plot, octave, libraries

The newest version of GNU Octave includes a graphical user interface with its own plotting capabilities in place of gnuplot.

I am working with a project written in C# and need to do some advanced plotting. It appears to me that the plotting capabilities of GNU Octave (contour plots and surface plots) are much more advanced than libraries like [zedgraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/?source=typ_redirect) or [oxyplot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/). Therefore I want to know whether the functionality is provided by some other library, or if Octave has created its own code and in which case whether that code is available as a standalone library?

Comment: did you mean graphics_toolkit fltk? It's not an invention by gnu octave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLTK

Comment: I mean something with plotting functions to create contour plots etc without having to recode the algorithms (e.g. via System.Drawing) from scratch. I had a look at FLTK, my understanding is that it is similar to other cross platform frameworks like Qt and doesn't have the specific drawing (plotting) functions I am looking for (which are a part of GNU octave).